# UPDATE operation from database using Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to update a value from database.
Here is my update code. It takes car as parameter.

```
[HttpPost("update")]
        public IActionResult Update(Car car)
        {
            var result = _carService.Update(car);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            return BadRequest(result);
        }
```

In postman, I choose post method and I am trying to write my url. However, how can I write my url? My method takes car parameter. I am trying to reach using car id. It never works.

For example I tried this:

"https://localhost:44383/api/cars/update/6"

I will add my postman picture. [image]

Comment: You have to show the Car class at least. Car can't be just  an integer.

Comment: Car class have 5 properties. Should I use in url all of them ?@Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update the car you have to use all properties, othewise not used properties will be null (or 0). If you don't use a primary key the record  will not be updated at all. You can use this url:

```
https://localhost:44383/api/cars/update
```

and since I have not seen your startup maybe you will need to add the whole route to your action ( you can try without it at first):

```
 [HttpPost("~/api/cars/update")]
 public IActionResult Update(Car car)
```

to test in postman add [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost("~/api/cars/update")]
 public IActionResult Update([FromBody] Car car)
```

and in postman your car should be shown as a raw Json:

```
{
  "Id":1,
  "ModelYear":2013,
  "Brand": "Ford",
... and so on
 
}
```